# javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    if (location.href.indexOf('?dest=') > 0)
        window.open('/about.aspx', '', '')
</script>
```

how do i make this work. Its in aspx file.

Comment: What exactly is happening?  Can you be a little more descriptive about any errors or strange behavior caused by the code?

Comment: And what is _supposed_ to happen?

Comment: im sorry. im very confused. i have first aspx page with <a href="login.aspx?dest=#" .. which goes to second page when clicked on it. On second page when i click "enter" i goto third page which has this code. I want to carry the dest=# to third page and based on this if condition a window should open. how do i achieve that?

Comment: FYI, `window.location.search` will return just the portion of the URL following the question mark, the querystring.

Comment: so how do i carry the querystring to 3rd page from the 2nd page and us the if condition?

Answer (score 2):

The following script will test for the existence of the 'dest=' key in the current page's querystring, and if it exists, will open a window to about.aspx with the querystring appended to the URL.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.search.indexOf('dest=') > 0) {
    window.open('/about.aspx' + window.location.search, '', '');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the window.open line to

```
window.location = '/about.aspx';
```

Include the semicolon, which is missing in your code.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't strictly require a semicolon at the end of a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `location.href...` part. It needs to be `window.location.href...`

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('?dest=') > 0){
    window.open('/about.aspx'+window.location.search, '', '');
}
```

Cheers

Comment: how do i get the ?dest to the third page. can i do
if (request.querystring('dest=') > 0){
    window.open('/about.aspx', '', '');
}
this is because i need to get the querystring from the previous page to this page